# What's the function of the Publish field of items in Sitecore

Tags: date, publishing, publish, sitecore

I am wondering what the function is of the Publish field of items in Sitecore. Just to be sure I am clear about what field I am talking about it's the field in the "Publishing" section of an item which is only shown when you check the "Standard fields" option.

Normally that field is not filled in and I expected it to be filled automatically by Sitecore when an item is published due to it's publishing restrictions settings but I am no longer sure about this.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 5):

The Publish field of Publishing section contains a date and time for an item to be published from. If you do not specify anything here, the item is publishable by default. These changes are applied to the whole item (the field is shared). If you'd like to change this for different versions, use the LifeTime section instead.

I would encourage you to get acquainted with [Content Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Content%20Cookbook.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, these fields can be used to properties of the publishment. For example, the date range when your page should be online.

If not, please give me a list of fields that are available.

Comment: In the publishing section you have the fields publish (date and time), unpublish (date and time), Publishing targets and Never publish. Note that I specifically am not talking about the opties the system displays when you select the "Change restrictions" option from the "Publishing" tab

Comment: About which options are you than specially talking about?

Comment: You use the "Change restrictions" option from the "Publishing" tab to specify that an item should be publish from a date/time. What I expected was that when that happens Sitecore would fill the Publish field with the date when the item was published. As far as I can determine now that is not happening.

Comment: That is right. These fields are meant to be used when you want to publish an item on a certain date, for example January 1st 2011.

Comment: But that doen't tell me what the function of the Publish field is. :)

Comment: I don't see which fields you mean. Maybe a screenshot will help

Comment: I am not allowed to upload images yet. If you like you can take a look at the following url. http://estate.aeres.nl/images/publish-field.jpg